# Amount of conjugacy classes equals elements of abelianization

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is the amount of conjugacy glasses of $G$ equal to the amount of elements of $G/N$ where $N$ is the normal subgroup generated by all commutators $g^{-1}h^{-1}gh$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are nontrivial [*perfect* groups](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Perfect_group), which are groups equal to their commutator subgroup. Thus $|G/N| = 1$, but any nontrivial group has more than one conjugacy class. Thus, your statement is not true in general.

It is true for abelian groups, though!

Comment: Ah thank you. How does an element look like in this subgroup generated by all commutators. Is it basically $g_{1}^{-1}h_{1}^{-1}g_{1}h_{1}g_{2}^{-1}h_{2}^{-1}g_{2}h_{2}.....$?

Comment: Yup! You’re absolutely right. Every element has that form.

Comment: why did I get negative points for this?

Comment: @user3397129 As a general rule, when you post a question on Math.SE it’s best to add context and your attempts to solve the problem to your post. Many people simply post their homework questions on here and want us to do it for them. Thus, people usually downvote posts that only ask a question (“Problem Statement Questions”). I answered because it doesn’t seem like this is a homework question.

Comment: @user3397129 This is also why the question is currently “on-hold.” If you edit your post with some background about how you came about the question and what your thoughts were about it beforehand, it would be more on topic for Math.SE and hopefully no longer be on hold.

Answer (score 1):

More concretely, this is false for $S_n$, $n\geq 3$, where $[S_n,S_n]=A_n$ and $|S_n/A_n|=2$.

But, the number of conjugacy classes in $S_n$ equals the number of partitions of $n$. 
For example, $S_3$ has $3$ conjugacy classes, $S_4$ has $5$, etc.